# decisionBar() won't blit the image to the screen when it is called

Tags: python, pygame, blit

```
    showScreen = True
    if showScreen == True:
        display = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 200))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Decision Bar Window")
        decisionBarImage = pygame.image.load('D:/Adriel/Documents/Python stuff/Games/Basic python game/Images/decision_bar.png')
        pygame.display.flip
        display.blit(decisionBarImage, (250,100))
```

In my code, the window will open but the image won't blit onto it. Please help.

Comment: `pygame.display.flip` does nothing at all. You missed the parentheses: `pygame.display.flip()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to blit the image to the screen surface before calling `pygame.display.flip()`.

Then you have to actually call the `flip()` function. In your code, the `()` are missing.

Also, you need an event loop, otherwise your window will freeze or maybe not display anything.

So your code should look like this:

```
    display = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 200))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Decision Bar Window")
    decisionBarImage = pygame.image.load('D:/Adriel/Documents/Python stuff/Games/Basic python game/Images/decision_bar.png')
    display.blit(decisionBarImage, (250,100))

    while True:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            pass # TODO: handle at least the QUIT event     

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: an error code appeared: Couldn't open D:/Adriel/Documents/Python stuff/Games/Basic python game/Images/decision_bar.png